# Como transformar um código de repetição "for" em "while" no JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for, while

```js
var ordinais = ['primeira', 'segunda', 'terceira', 'quarta'];
var media=0;

for (var i = 0; i < ordinais.length; i++) {
    var nota = prompt("Informe a " + ordinais[i] + " nota: ");
    if (nota === "" || !nota) nota = 0;
    media += parseFloat(nota,3);
}

media /= ordinais.length;

if (media >= 7) {
    document.write("Aprovado");
} else if (media <= 5) {
    document.write("Reprovado");
} else if (media = 6){
    document.write("Recuperação");
}
```

Comment: Tem algum motivo para isso? O `for` é mais adequado nesse caso (já que lhe permite manter o estado da posição da iteração na própria construção sintática). Além disso, porque passou `3` no segundo argumento de `parseFloat`? Essa função só aceita [um argumento](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat#Par%C3%A2metros).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Um `for` é composto por 3 blocos: uma inicialização, uma condição indicando quando deve terminar a repetição do laço e um processamento que deve acontecer todas as vezes que termina um passo da repetição.

A primeira é tranquilo reproduzir usando O `while` porque basta inicializar antes do laço. O único inconveniente pode ser o escopo da variável ser além do bloco do laço como ocorre no `for` dependendo de como declara.

A segunda parte é o que ficará no `while` já que a única função do comando é a condição.

A terceira parte a ser modificada pode ser problemático em alguns casos onde tem um `continue` porque a execução mudaria e o resultado seria outro se não tomar certos cuidados, mas não é o caso do seu código, então coloquei o incrementador dentro do laço como último comando, seria assim:

```js
var ordinais = ['primeira', 'segunda', 'terceira', 'quarta'];
var media = 0;
var i = 0;
while (i < ordinais.length) {
    var nota = prompt("Informe a " + ordinais[i] + " nota: ");
    if (nota === "" || !nota) nota = 0;
    media += parseFloat(nota);
    i++;
}
media /= ordinais.length;
if (media >= 7) document.write("Aprovado");
else if (media <= 5) document.write("Reprovado");
else document.write("Recuperação");
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/While.js).

Eu não faria isso nesse caso, ainda que não mude nada relevante. O `for` parece a solução perfeita.

Corrigi alguns erros do código. Mudei a última condição porque tinha notas que faziam nada. Ainda deve estar erado porque a faixa de recuperação é muita estranha, mas sem enunciado não posso corrigir isso (tinha outro erro na condição, mas tirando ela deixa de ter). Ainda existe possibilidade de digitação inválida dar problema na execução.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var ordinais = ['primeira', 'segunda', 'terceira', 'quarta'];
var media=0;
var i = 0

while (i < ordinais.length ) {    
    var nota = prompt("Informe a " + ordinais[i] + " nota: ");
    if (nota === "" || !nota) nota = 0;
    media += parseFloat(nota,3);
    i++
}

media /= ordinais.length;

if (media >= 7) {
    document.write("Aprovado");
} else if (media <= 5) {
    document.write("Reprovado");
} else if (media = 6){
    document.write("Recuperação");
}
```

Você define a variável `i` antes dai é só fazer o mesmo esquema que para `i` menor que o `array.length` `i++`, porém coloca o `i++` no final se não ele ficará com `+1` na frente dos index do array.

Answer (score -1):

Para transformar em while, vc precisa criar um contador na mão, exemplo:

```
let i = 0;

white(i<=10){
  console.log(i);
  i = i + 1
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
var ordinais = ['primeira', 'segunda', 'terceira', 'quarta'];
var media=0;
var count=0;

while(count < ordinais.length){
    var nota = prompt("Informe a " + ordinais[count] + " nota: ");
    if (nota === "" || !nota) nota = 0;
    media += parseFloat(nota,3);
    count+=1;
}

media /= ordinais.length;

if (media >= 7) {
    document.write("Aprovado");
} else if (media <= 5) {
    document.write("Reprovado");
} else if (media = 6){
    document.write("Recuperação");
}
```